# When sys.stdin.readline().split() is sorted, the integer sequence is weird

Tags: python

If you are given two arrays aligned with array matching problems, you combine the arrays and then re-output them in order of size. I brought a sys instead of input to get an integer input. The result is that 11 isn't the last one, it's the next one. Why is this happening?

Input:

```
5 4
2 3 6 7 8
1 8 9 11
```

Desired result:

```
1 2 3 6 7 8 8 9 11
```

Code:

```
import sys

a,b = input().split()
a = int(a)
b = int(b)

li1 = sys.stdin.readline().split()
li2 = sys.stdin.readline().split()
li = li1+li2
li.sort()


for i in range(a+b):
    print(li[i], end=" ")
```

Current results:

```
1 11 2 3 6 7 8 8 9
```

Comment: you have list of strings `"1" "11" "2" "3" "6" "7" "8" "8" "9"`, not numbers `1 11 2 3 6 7 8 8 9` - and when you sort strings then `"11"` is lower then `"2"` because it compares first char `"1"` (in "11") with first char `"2". You have to convert all elements on list to `int()`

Comment: Your input array looks like it's showing up all in one line. You could put it in a code block to make it more clear what lines are actually being passed. Also, mixing `sys.stdin.readline` and `input` is generally not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your lists `li1` and `li2` hold string data and not integers.
You have rightly casted `a` and `b` as `int` values, but the lists are still string.

This has resulted in your list being sorted in [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order). Convert these values to `int` using any method to get your answer.

```
li1 = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())) # Using map
li2 = sys.stdin.readline().split()
li2 = [int(x) for x in li2]                        # Using list comprehension
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for telling me in detail like this!! You've been very helpful. XD

Comment: It's cool. Then you would want to accept the answer and close the question.